CMAK has zero brokers
I am trying to create a topic after creating a cluster within CMAK ( https://medium.com/simform-engineering/set-up-kafka-ecosystem-on-local-machine-1a00a436c0ba ).
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.0.1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
  kafka_manager:
    image: kafkamanager/kafka-manager
    container_name: kafka-manager
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      ZK_HOSTS: "zookeeper:2181"
      APPLICATION_SECRET: "random-secret"


As you can see has the cluster no brokers available.
When i try to create a topic

i get this error.
Yikes! replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers 0

Can you please help me with this error

Check the broker logs. Did it start successfully?

Sorry i realy new to Kafka. Where can i find the broker logs ?

Logs of the container? docker logs kafka for example
